# Can't get custom media queries to work with bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm using a themed version of the Twitter Bootstrap layout to build a site and all of my custom CSS is working out just fine with the exception of the @media queries.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<section id="lessons" class="bg-black no-padding lesson-content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img src="/clients/wt/images/lesson_01.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
        <img src="/clients/wt/images/lesson_03.jpg" alt="Image 3" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 hideable">
        <img src="/clients/wt/images/lesson_02.jpg" alt="Image 2" />
        <img src="/clients/wt/images/lesson_04.jpg" alt="Image 4" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 text-right expandable">
        <h3>Content Title</h3>
        <p>More content here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .hideable {
    display: none;
  }
  .expandable {
    width: 66.6666667%;
  }
}
```

The goal here is that the .hideable column will disappear and the .expandable one will fill its place.  If you want to see the full development site it's available at http://tentenstudios.com/clients/wt/ If you resize the window you'll see that the middle photos in the "Lessons" area do not disappear.

Comment: Seems to be working for me. I think you might want to apply it to a higher max-width? Around 1200px maybe?

Comment: Ahh, you're right -- I had no idea I needed to set the max-width that high!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap CSS contains:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.col-lg-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

and

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11,
.col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3,
.col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6,
.col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9 {
  float: left;
}
```

To achieve what I think you are looking for you would have to maintain both those styles beyond the min-width of 1200px. So something like this should work:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-4 {
     width: 33.33333333%;
     float: left;
  }
  .hideable {
    display: none;
  }
  .expandable {
    width: 66.6666667%;
  }
}
```